# Hide sender's address in email

Tags: vb.net, email

I am working on visual studio 2012 vb.net coding. I was asked to create an application to my company that sends emails to clients but they want to display company's name at client's screen and the email address should be hidden. My code is working properly except this point(hiding sender address) and I am using smtp client.
Any hints?

Below is my code :

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
'mail.From = New MailAddress("Me@domain.com", "Me")
mail.From = New MailAddress("""Me "" <Me@domain.com>")
mail.[To].Add("somebody@domain.com")
mail.Subject = "Test email from App"
mail.Body = "Dear somebody, this email was sent from our project as a   test email, Regards."

Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("localhost")
Try
     nsmtp.Send(mail)
Response.Write("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")
Catch exc As Exception
     Response.Write("Send failure: " & exc.ToString())
End Try
```

Comment: Does your provider support this function?

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the quotes. MailAddress("Me  <Me@domain.com>")

Comment: Try this `mail.From = New MailAddress("someone@domain.com", "someonefriendlyname")` ***or this*** `mail.From = "\YOURNAME\ <yourname@domain.com>"`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys but unfortunately I still have the same problem ... @Zaggler mail.from supports MailAddress not a String